# Error when trying to inject dependency

Tags: go

I'm trying refactor some code to use dependency injection for the [Docker client library](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client#Client.Ping) I use in my code. I created an interface with the method I want to be able to mock

```
type DockerClient interface {
    Ping(context.Context) (types.Ping, error)
}

func NewDockerUtil() (*DockerUtil, error) {
    var dockerClient *DockerClient
    var err error
    dockerClient, err = client.NewEnvClient() //Reports incompatible types in binary and unary expressions.
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &DockerUtil{
        Client:        dockerClient,
    }, nil
}

type DockerUtil struct{
    Client        *DockerClient
}
```

But when I try to assign it I get `Reports incompatible types in binary and unary expressions.` What exactly do I need to change?

Comment: use `DockerClient` instead of `*DockerClient`

Comment: @Motakjuq I've tried this but you get the same error

Comment: I didn't see it before, but `&DockerUtil{....` is using `client` instead of `dockerClient`

Comment: @Motakjuq that's a copy/paste mistake I'll fix it, the compiler error in question occurs on the commented line

Comment: Please post the whole, exact error message. It probably has the necessary information for us to figure out the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's start with using `interface{}`, when you define interface don't use pointer definition, [good read here](https://medium.com/@agileseeker/go-interfaces-pointers-4d1d98d5c9c6).

```
type DockerUtil struct{
    Client        DockerClient
}
```

And moby [Client](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client#Client) implements lot of methods and you would like to do `interface` for selective methods.

> Right way to do is via Type assertion. Good read [Effective Go - Type assertions](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions) and [Spec - Type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

***Note:*** try this code, I don't have docker env in my machine to test.

```
func NewDockerUtil() (*DockerUtil, error) {
    dockerClient, err := client.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &DockerUtil{
        Client:        dockerClient.(DockerClient),
    }, nil
}
```

**Note:**

Using `DockerUtil.Client`, you can call only `Ping` method since your interface `DockerClient` has definition of `Ping` method.

---

If you would like to call all the methods supported by `client.Client` later on then you have to do type assertion-

```
dockerClient := DockerUtil.Client.(*client.Client)
```

Comment: the error I get now is `non-interface type *Client on the left`

Comment: I figured it out, I was using the wrong `context` pkg

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: Well, not really, the solution was to make sure i was using the correct `context` package, I didn't know that Docker was using `golang.org/x/net/context` as opposed to the stdlib `context`

Comment: Okay, I believe answer gives an information for interface implementation. Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah not using pointers for interface was helpful I'll give you the answer